# Dataframe to pivot table

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I am working with a dataframe in Jupyter Notebook and am wondering how to pivot my data using the Python pandas library.

Please see the dataframe/table I am working with:
[image: dataframe-table]

Pivot table I created in Excel that I would like to replicate using pandas:
[image]

Comment: You can use `pd.pivot_table` which will be the most intuitive. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Although I agree with @DavidGibson, you can also try 'pd.crosstab(index=df["column"], columns = df["column(s)"], margins=True)' - This compares the index and column to have the count.